# Does reloading AdMob Banner Ads make more profit than showing just once?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I've implemented **AdMob**'s **BannerAd** to my app's bottom. My app has just one screen/page, and I am showing ad at the bottom of it.

If I reload **BannerAd** in every 1 minute using this code

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (Timer t) => myBanner..load()..show() );
}
```

will it be more profitable?

So, if user stays at my app's screen for 9 minutes and sees 9 reloaded different **BannerAd**s, will it make any difference to my earning, or, maybe, (does) **AdMob** automatically refreshes BannerAds ?

What is the best practise, if anyone knows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely refresh advertisement after **minimum 30 second** ad show, but i highly recommend you to avoid this because AdMob automatically update ad after few time.

Moreover, i also experience that there is more user engagement to advertisement when user watch it for longer period of time(around 1 minutes).